# Covariance in Robot Pose from Covariance in Line Segments

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, bivariate

The solution to this might be completely obvious, so I apologize beforehand. The purpose of this question is for me to get better intuition on how to use covariance matrices of correlated variables in a real-world example.

Let's say I have a robot equipped with a lidar. The robot is able to extract line segments from the 2D point cloud to find a set of line segments. The line segments are simply pairs of endpoints, but the extractor also calculates statistics on the line that contains the segment. Namely, for each line $l_{i} = (r_{i}, \theta_{i})$ we also have $\sigma_{rr}$, $\sigma_{r\theta}$, and $\sigma_{\theta\theta}$. Below is a drawing of a line in normal form.

[image: Line in normal form]

Now suppose I have the best guess $(x,y)$ of where my robot is on a map. For simplicity, we can assume that the map is composed entirely of perfectly horizontal and vertical line segments. See the image below. The black lines are the map, and the red lines are the segments extracted from the point cloud. The robot is pictured at $(x,y)$.

[image: Robot on a map]

You can see that the segments do not perfectly align with the walls in the map, but they are close enough that we can be certain which line segments correspond to which lines on the map.

**Question:** Using the covariance of the line segment parameters, how can we calculate the covariance of the robot pose $p = (x,y,\theta)$?

**My attempt:** To calculate the robot's orientation, I note that the vertical line segments have $\theta = 0°$ and the horizontal segments have $\theta = 90°$. So after shifting the angles of the horizontal segments by 90° so that all lines are centered about 0°, the robot's orientation would just be a weighted sum with the weight of each segment being inversely proportional to the variance of the angle of that segment.

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\theta_i}{\sigma_{\theta_i}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{\theta_i}^{-1}}$$
$$\hat{\sigma_{\theta}} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_{\theta_i}^{-1}}$$

Now, given the best estimate of the $x,y$ position of the robot, I'd like to find the variance of $x,y$ using the uncertainty of the line segments. This is where things get confusing for me. I think that it will have something to do with the marginal distributions of $x$ and $y$. Really what I want is to calculate the covariance of $x,y,$ and $\theta$, but I'm lost on the next step to take.

Thank you in advance for your help.